# Swing GridBagLayout can't distribute(remove) empty spaces

Tags: java, swing

Even though I have read something about weighty I couldn't remove spaces given code fragment below:

```
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    scrollPane.setViewportView(panel);
    GridBagLayout gbl_panel = new GridBagLayout();
    GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints ();
    gbl_panel.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    gbl_panel.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0};
    gbl_panel.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    gbl_panel.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    panel.setLayout(gbl_panel);
    for(int i = 0;i<3;i++){
        gc.gridy = i;
        panel.add(new JButton("hi"),gc);
    }
```

[That's what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgaNt.png)

[That's what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zXVt.png)

It distributes these 3 buttons with equal spaces(top,middle,bottom)
If the components total size is bigger than panel's size(for example add 10 button) there is no problem.But if the total size of components smaller than panel's size it distributes all spaces.I want to set my components line by line(top to bottom withoud any spaces between components)
Sorry for inconvenience thanks !

Comment: Your `rowWeights` array has two elements.  The second element in that array is a nonzero weight, so it’s no surprise the second row in your layout is allocated extra space.

Comment: How to remove that allocated extra space ?

Comment: Specify a row weight for each row.  Any row with a weight of zero will be allocated no extra space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `GridBagConstraints` `fill` field

From JavaDocs

```
 * This field is used when the component's display area is larger
 * than the component's requested size. It determines whether to
 * resize the component, and if so, how.
```

`fill` defines whether component should be resized and how.

`weight` defines how much extra space the component should use

UPDATE:

Add any JComponent e.g. `JPanel` after all your buttons and set `fill` for the `JPanel` and `weight=1`. Your buttons' weights are 0 so all the extra space is added to the panel.

Comment: But I do not want to resize buttons size.I just want to fill gaps and set them line by line.(top to bottom all spaces should be in the bottom not between buttons)BTW,thanks for your interest.

Comment: It fills and removes spaces but still resizing my buttons in order to fill all spaces :(  I dont want to resize.Just want to remove all gaps between my components and add these gaps to end of the panel.

Comment: I uploaded 2 pictures

Comment: No need to post pics. Read here http://sscce.org/ whats is SSCCE and create runnable example